# Writting elements in the boundary of a set as combination of other elements

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be a $n\times m$ $(n>m)$ matrix with $x_{ij}\geq 0$ (not all $x_{ij}$ can be zero). Let $%
\mathbf{\Lambda }=\left\{ \lambda \left\vert \lambda \in \mathbb{R}%
_{+}^{n},\lambda _{i}\geq 0,\sum \lambda _{i}=1\right. \right\} .$ Consider
the set $\mathbf{Y}$ of convex combinations of the rows of $\mathbf{X,}$ $%
\mathbf{Y=}\left\{ y\left\vert y=\lambda ^{\top }\mathbf{X,}\lambda \mathbf{%
\in \Lambda }\right. \right\} .$ This is a closed and convex set, and is
equal to its closure, $\overline{\mathbf{Y}}$. Let $\overline{\mathbf{Y}}^{C}
$ denote the closure of the complement of $\mathbf{Y.}$

Although I haven't done it, I guess that it should not be too difficult to prove that for every $\overline{y}\in \overline{\mathbf{Y}}\cap \overline{\mathbf{Y}}%
^{C}$ element of the boundary of $\mathbf{Y,}$ there exists $%
\overline{\lambda }\in \mathbf{\Lambda }$ such that $\overline{\lambda }%
^{\top }\mathbf{X=}\overline{y}$ and $\overline{\lambda }_{i}=0$ for $n-m$
components.

What I'm really interested in is the following:

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}_{++}^{n}$ with $\alpha _{i}>1,$ and, abusing
notation, let $\lambda ^{\alpha }=\left( \lambda _{1}^{\alpha _{1}},\lambda
_{2}^{\alpha _{2}},...,\lambda _{n}^{\alpha _{n}}\right) $ for some $\lambda
\in \mathbf{\Lambda .}$ If we now think of $\mathbf{Y}^{\prime }\mathbf{=}%
\left\{ y^{\prime }\left\vert y^{\prime }=\left( \lambda ^{\alpha }\right)
^{\top }\mathbf{X,}\lambda \mathbf{\in \Lambda }\right. \right\} ,$ the
previous claim is still true for some elements of the boundary (in $\mathbb{R}%
^{2}$, those in the
southwestern part of the boundary, so to speak). The intuition comes from some "symmetry" argument: When $n=2$ and $\alpha$ is such that $\alpha _{i}<1$ for all $i$, it is easy to prove that elements in the southwestern boundary of the set are the result of $\lambda \gg 0.$ In fact, it is easy to prove this for any $n$, but it is easiest to think of the "southwestern" boundary in $\mathbb{R}%
^{2}.$

Comment: This is not true. Take, e.g. $X=0$.

Comment: Perhaps I should've pointed out that not all $x_{íj}$ can be zero @daw